# Laravel rename relationship in result for the same names

Tags: php, laravel

here as you can see i have two `car_model` both of main table field and relation name:

```
App\Models\Product {#1478 ▼
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "products"
  ...
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
  #attributes: array:21 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "company_id" => 1
    ...
    "car_model" => "test"
    ...
  ]
  #original: array:21 [▶]
  ...
  #relations: array:5 [▼
    "company" => App\Models\Company {#1506 ▶}
    "car_model" => App\Models\CarModel {#1508 ▼
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "car_models"
      #attributes: array:6 [▼
        "id" => 1
        "title" => "test"
        "created_at" => ":07:25"
        "updated_at" => ":07:58"
      ]
      ...
      +mediaConversions: []
      +mediaCollections: []
      #deletePreservingMedia: false
      #unAttachedMediaLibraryItems: []
    }
    ...
}
```

when i try to get `car_model` in relation ship and having both `car_model` how can i get relation data? for example:

```php
$products->first()->car_model->title
```

`Product` model:

```php
    public function car_model(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(CarModel::class);
    }
```

and my query:

```php
$this->products = Product::with(
    [
        'car_model',
    ]
)->get();
```

Comment: why you have 2 car_models, it is a bad design

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur yes, its a bad design. is any way to rename the relationship in result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. after converting `object` into `array` i can access to `car_model` as a `relationship`:

```php
$i=$products->first()->toArray();
echo $i['car_model']['title'];
```

or

```php
echo ($products->first()->toArray())['car_model']['title']
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to rename relation with car_models or other name except car_model:

```
public function car_models(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(CarModel::class);
    }
```

and query can be changed to this

```
$this->products = Product::with(
    [
        'car_models',
    ]
)->get();
```

then return it with

```
$products->first()->car_models->title
```